# How long will it take to anneal at a lower temperature?

Tags: materials, metallurgy, metals, chemistry

Someone is trying to anneal a brass casting to minimize the segregation of Zinc. He likes the results of annealing at 400 Celsius for 3 hours, but the high temperature produces problems with residual stresses. Instead, he wants to anneal at 250 Celsius. How long will it take to achieve the same results when annealing at 250 Celsius?

I have no idea where to begin with this problem. I couldn't find any examples of a similar problem in the textbook or online, and we didn't do one in class. Can anyone help?

Comment: Reading around, 250C might be below the phase transition temperature of brass which means it won't anneal at all.

Answer (score 2):

The alloy makes a difference. If it is essentially copper and zinc like 70:30 (cartridge brass, or admiralty if you put in one pre-cent tin) or lower amounts of zinc: Nothing much happens with the phases. Hard to guess why he thinks there is segration or residual stresses after a slow cool from 400 C. Actually a water quench would give a solution anneal, good for improved ductility. I think you had trouble finding references because there is no problem with residual stress in brass unless it is cold rolled. Brasses are going to have annealing twins (metallographically ), maybe that is causing confusion.

Comment: I think my professor wrote the residual stress part as a random comment for why he wants to redo it at 250C. More of the focus I think is on what the results of annealing would be after 400C for 3 hours and how you could replicate that at 250C.

Answer (score 1):

I used a different search engine and may have found something useful.

"When cold worked brass is progressively heated, the first effect, at about 250ºC, is for the internal stresses to be relieved. This prevents stress corrosion cracking subsequently occurring and also minimises the amount of distortion which may occur during machining. This low temperature heat treatment, which should be applied for 1⁄2 to 1 hour, is known as ‘stress-relief annealing’ and has little, if any, measurable effect on the mechanical properties of the material. The improved strength due to the cold working is therefore retained. As the temperature is increased further, a rather more fundamental change occurs at about 400ºC and above and the material starts to ‘anneal’ or soften with time at temperature."

So with this information, I believe that one could not achieve the same effects at 250C as at 400C no matter how long they held it at that temperature or how long they cooled it. However, they could reduce the residual stresses of the original 400C annealed brass by heating it at 250C for 1/2 to 1 hour.

http://www.nationalbronze.com/pub-117---the-brasses_whole_web-pdf.pdf

Comment: THis makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion here:

"Annealing is often confused with Tempering. Both can be considered forms of Heat Treatment, but, with the risk of oversimplifying matters – Tempering takes the metal to a lower temperature and tends to harden metals, Annealing is a shorter, hotter process and softens them.1

We don’t want to harden the metal any more than it already is. So, we are talking about high temperatures for brief periods of time. Under-anneal and no real benefit will occur, over-anneal, and you risk over softening your brass. Something you don’t really want when it’s meant to be directing and controlling and explosion.

Brass Annealing Temperature
Online, the suggested temperature your brass needs to get varies a bit, ranging from 600 to 800 degrees Fahrenheit (that’s 315 to 420 Celsius for us in metric land). The average recommendation seems to sit in the 700 F range though (370 C)."

https://thebloke.co.nz/understanding-brass-annealing/

One one of the online forums, the consensus seems to suggest heating to 650 degrees Fahrenheit for 8s to 15 minutes. I believe the wide range of heating time is due to the various size of the samples.

**ADD:**

The stress relieving temperature is normally between 550 and 650°C for steel parts. Soaking time is about one to two hours. After the soaking time the components should be cooled down slowly in the furnace or in air. A slow cooling speed is important to avoid tensions caused by temperature differences in the material, this is especially important when stress relieving larger components.

**The temperature for stress relieving copper parts is, depending on the alloy, 150-275°C and for brass components 250-500°C.**

Comment: The "bloke" reference shows a basic misunderstanding of what is happening. They are stress relieving , not annealing, not tempering.  I suspect annealed cartridge brass would not work in an automatic gun, too soft.

Comment: @blacksmith37 The article made no mistake, it talks nothing about stress-relieving. I cited it to point out that annealing at 250 degrees C would likely harden the metal instead of softening. (See the last sentence in the first paragraph of the question)

Comment: @blacksmith37 Find a web page full of links to articles that talk about annealing gun parts for your info use, though I am not positive any of them cover brass cartridges. https://www.bing.com/search?q=annealing+of+gun+barrel&cvid=e86bae27363c42dea4e9ad4036bca3b0&aqs=edge..69i57.21229j0j9&FORM=ANAB01&PC=LCTS

Comment: Yeah, the focus of the question is not on residual stresses, but rather on annealing at a lower temperature and producing the same results. The residual stress part was likely a throwaway comment.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Annealing, stress relieving, and normalizing are all technically distinct terms?

Comment: @DKN, yes. Normalizing applies only to steels . A recrystallize/grain refinement.  Stress relieve is below critical temperature , also called PWHT ( post weld heat-treat).

Comment: @blacksmith37 I would make a question but the terms are all over the place that I'm not even sure what to ask. Some sources seem to use different terms for the same thing (i.e. process annealing = stress relieving) and many seem to use the term stress-relieving as the goal of a process rather than the name of a process.

Comment: @r13; My second job , I heat-treated many thousands of gun parts; all were quenched and tempered . The "softest" was a RC 45 front sight. Many were for the US government , (who else needs all those guns?) . Our HT shop reached the highest military AQL , that is they only tested about 1 per 500 parts because we had excellent quality. In process some were annealed as an intermediate step.

Comment: Now I just found a list of 9 different types of annealing :S

Comment: @DKN; I was going to mention process anneal, subcritical anneal, solution anneal , etc, but did not think it would help.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I'll make a question trying to get the high level outline of the terms.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I've no question about your expertise and qualification on this matter as I've followed many of your answers, as the learning source, from time to time. But this time both of us may have misinterpreted the OP's thought. After further thinking, I guess he is going to heat treat to 400 degrees C, then cool it to 250 degrees C to perform the process of stress relief,  However, he's not sure how long it will take to get rid of the residual stress. Is this sound right?

Comment: I can't guess what the problem is. ASME ( aka the Code) requires one hour per inch thickness to stress relieve steel . Unless the brass casting is substantially thicker than 3 inches , the planned stress relieve is serious overkill.

Comment: @blacksmith37 This is a piece of valuable information. I suggest updating your answer with this comment if it is not already addressed.